# Property value in <s:textfield> struts2

Tags: struts2

How to set propety value in `<s:textfield>`

I tried `<s:textfield name="customerName" label="Customer Name" value='<s:property value="userInfo.customerName"' />` but it didn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not use a tag inside of a tag. Use OGNL instead!

```xml
<s:textfield name = "customerName" 
            label = "Customer Name" 
            value = "%{userInfo.customerName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OGNL (Object Graph Navigation Language) to get value in any kind of field of struts. If you will not get value please check setter and getter of the variable.

```html
<s:textfield name="transValueChange" id="transValueChange" 
             value ="%{transValue}" theme="simple" maxLength="30"
             onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
</s:textfield>
```

OR

```html
<s:select name="propCode" id="propCode" list="propClassMasMap" theme="simple"
          value="%{propCode}" onchange="" cssClass="text">
</s:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
<table>
    <s:label>User Name:</s:label>
    <s:textfield name="user.userid" cssClass="tb5" type="text" placeholder="User Name" value="%{#session.userid}" disabled="true" /> 
</table>
```

The disabled attribute is not mandatory, I used it to disable the textfield that way the values will be retrieved from the DB and will be disable for the user to make changes on it.